# Rails/Mongoid dynamic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nosql, mongoid

I'm working on a CMDB-like application in RoR, having a root "node" model whose submodels like "server", "firewall", "router", ... will inherit, adding their own specific fields.

Because each submodel will have specific fields, I will use MongoDB with Mongoid for its schemaless design.

Because I will have hundreds of fields, I would like to generate submodels dynamically, based on a configuration file that will also be used to generate my views. This would help to synchronize views and models and avoid some errors.

I don't want to use Mongoid "Dynamic Attributes" because I don't want any data to be blindly persisted so I need to enforce some kind of dynamic schema based on model.

Is there a way to dynamically enhance my root model with specific fields based on a configuration file in YAML, containing submodels fields, types, validations, ...?

I don't think using this configuration file to generate my views will be a big deal but I don't see how to do that for my models.

Maybe there's already a Gem doing that? (I've searched before asking) If yes, is it compatible with Mongoid? (I hope it does because this kind of dynamic model would only be possible with schemaless NoSQL databases).

Comment: So, what are you expecting these configuration files to do, that Mongoid doesn't already do? You can turn off allowing dynamic fields (that aren't specified in your model) with Mongoid already, and then have a list of embedded models for your root 'node' that reference models for Server, Firewall, Router, et al. Or are you looking for something else beyond that?

Comment: I don't want my model definition (fields, validations, ...) to be hard written in the class but generated from a config file.

Comment: Looks like Mongoid Model Builder gem might fit your needs: https://github.com/porecreat/mongoid_model_builder